# Is it possible to use both Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.Beta in the same app?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm writing some C# code targeting .NET 4.8, which needs to use Microsoft Graph. It works OK with Microsoft.Graph SDK (V1), however when I try to switch to Beta, I'm getting compilation errors like

```
Error CS0433    The type 'GraphServiceClient' exists in both 'Microsoft.Graph.Beta, Version=0.29.0.0 <...>' and 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=1.19.0.0 <...>'
```

The reason being that one other nuget I'm using, namely SharePointPnPCoreOnline, unfortunately depends on Microsoft.Graph 1.19.

It would seem that there should be no problem using both assemblies, as - according to the current documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/use-beta) - Beta should use its own namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;
```

Unfortunately it is wrong, both libraries share the same namespace Microsoft.Graph. The code above results in

```
Error CS0234    The type or namespace name 'Beta' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Graph' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I'm trying to use compiler options to resolve the assembly, but it's extremely convoluted under VS2019 - so far no luck.

But I'm wondering why can't I find anything on this issue, I'm surely not the only one - can it be that I miss something obvious? Please help :)

Comment: If i am not wrong, Error CS0433 is a compiler error. Two different assemblies referenced in your application contain the same namespace and type, which produces ambiguity. To resolve this error, use the alias feature of the -reference (C# Compiler Options) compiler option or do not reference one of your assemblies to see if it helps you to move forward.

Comment: @Dev: Unfortunately it didn't help. I mentioned it in my question before you even answered. You started your comment with "If I am not wrong". I'm pretty sure you knew you weren't wrong, because the rest of your comment is copy-pasted from MS documentation for CS0234. Appreciate it, but let's try to keep the noise down.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you solved this, but I solved this by adding an alias to Microsoft.Graph.Beta package. Then when referencing, add this to be able to reference your beta-endpoints or resources. Change `MSGraphBeta` to whatever you added as an alias to your package.

```
extern alias MSGraphBeta;
using GraphBeta = MSGraphBeta.Microsoft.Graph;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I completely forgot about the "extern alias" feature! I ended up writing my own thin wrapper for MS Graph calls and don't use SDK for the time being. Bur I'll definitely test you approach!

Comment: Any idea how to do this with .Net Core?

Comment: Aliases can be used with .Net Core as well.